# Problem with full-screen applications and fractional scaling for HiDPI monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, fullscreen, hdpi

This is another problem I experience with fractional scaling/HiDPI and Ubuntu 20.10.

I have a setup with 2 normal DPI monitors and one HiDPI with 150% zoom.
The problem is when an application requests full screen (i.e. firefox and a video in youtube, VLC, or even a wine game). Then the application changes (properly) to full screen, there's a flicker, the resolution changes, the screen flickers again, another resolution change and the monitors are left in a total mess.

With firefox/youtube things are even worse. The screen goes into infinite loop of changing resolutions.

If I disable fractional scaling and put everything into 100% or 200%, no problem appears. Even if I keep on fractional scaling, but put either 100% or 200%, still not problem appears. Same, if I use fullscreen on a monitor with *no* fractional scaling. But, when I try to put full screen for a fractional scaling monitor, chaos emerges.

I am really confused on how to approach this problem... any ideas?

**EDIT** I am using X11 backend, not wayland and Ubuntu's Gnome as Window manager.

**EDIT 2** When I change from default Gnome to Budgie, there I can launch fullscreen apps correctly. So it looks like a Gnome issue. Any hint how to solve it or where should I report it?

Comment: I am also experiencing this same problem but on ubuntu 22.04. Did you managed to solve this already or did you open a bug report?

Comment: Experiencing same on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Gnome

Answer (score 0):

The related issue trace may be here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1890141

And you may resolve it by installing a gnome shell extension: https://github.com/kazysmaster/gnome-shell-extension-disable-unredirect